# Real users (users with a valid login shell)

Tags: shell-script

How can I print the real users(in a script if possible)? I know that the real users have a valid login shell and i know that the valid login shell can be found in /etc/shells. But I don't know how to take the users (from /etc/passwd) that have the respective shell.

Comment: Is this an isolated system or do you need to consider users in LDAP, NIS, Active Directory, etc.?

Comment: It's an isolated system

Comment: `grep -F "$(grep -v '^#' /etc/shells)" /etc/passwd`

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F: 'NR == FNR {shells[$0]; next} $NF in shells' /etc/{shells,passwd}
```

or, grep but it's less precise

```
grep -Ff /etc/shells /etc/passwd
```